Use reflect to make a new struct from unknown struct type
I have a function that expects to receive an array of pointers to structs of unknown definitions. I want to be able to create a new instance of the unknown struct, assign values to it, and then append it to the given array.
// Someone using this package example:
type Foo Struct {
    Val int
    Nested []Bar
}

type Bar struct {
   Val int
}

func main() {
    var foos []*Foo
    Mutate(&foos)
    
    // Expect foos[0] to be:
    // Foo{Val: 1, Nested: { Bar{Val: 2} } }
}

// My function (no access to definition of Foo)
func Mutate(target any) {
    // This is where i am stuck
    t := reflect.TypeOf(target).Elem()
    // => []*main.Foo
    // I have no idea of how to create a new instance 
    // of main.Foo or even see what fields it has.
}


Try this code:
func Mutate(target any) {
    // Get reflect.Value for slice.
    slice := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()

    // Create pointer to value. Set a field in the value.
    valuet := slice.Type().Elem().Elem()
    valuep := reflect.New(valuet)
    value := valuep.Elem()
    value.FieldByName("Val").SetInt(1)

    // Append value pointer to slice set resulting slice
    // in target.       
    slice.Set(reflect.Append(slice, valuep))
}

https://play.golang.com/p/fAxkHexQheC

While Jeremys answer goes in the right direction, the resulting foos[0] is Foo{Val: 1, Nested: nil }. Setting hierarchical values via reflect can be tricky, so may I suggest using JSON for this?
First generate an new Foo value and append it to the slice:
    t := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    foo := reflect.New(t.Type().Elem().Elem())
    t.Set(reflect.Append(t, foo))

then use JSON so fill in the value Foo{Val:1 Nested:[Bar{Val:2}]}:
    v := `{"Val":1,"Nested":[{"Val":2}]}`
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(v), foo.Interface()); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // do some reasonable error handling here
    }

See the result on the Go Playground.
